# Load Balancing JSF2.0 Application in Tomcat 6.X

Tags: jsf, jsf-2, tomcat6, apache

We have an application which is developed with JSF2.0.
The application is running one multiple server instances.
We did not used any sessions, SessionScope.
We only used @RequestScoped, @ViewScoped, @ApplicationScoped.

The app.war is running in server1 and server2.
For the @ViewScoped beans we are facing issues.

How to load balance the Tomcat servers with httpd, for JSF saved views.
So I wonder how this would match switching incoming requests to a set of 
load-balanced web servers. How those above data would remain consistent?

Comment: This is [the n-th time](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1457747/uday?tab=questions) that `<pre></pre>` tags were removed from your question. Please stop adding them for text which does not represent code at all.

Comment: ohh ok, i am not getting the proper formatting for question.
That is why every time i used to put <pre> tags.
However, from next time i will not put them. thank you so much.